# Redis how to reset timeout on cache hit?

Tags: redis, node-redis

I am using redis for storing some data like a cache.

I am using `EX 60` to store data only for `60s`.

My question is:

Is there any way how to reset timeout on cache hit?

Example:

I create cache item at 12:00:00, key will expired in 12:01:00.

I will call `get` at 12:00:30, the timeout will be restarted to 12:01:30.

Iam usin node JS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such a command. But you can achieve it via multi or lua script.

[Feature new command GETEX](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2762)